# How do I distinguish between escaped and unescaped Unicode characters?

Tags: ruby, unicode

I'm working on a script to check some translated message files for Java. Our message source doesn't allow un-escaped Unicode characters within a format block:

```
{0,number,¤UNESCAPED# ###}

1.9.2p290 :001 > unescaped = "{0,number,¤UNESCAPED# ###}"
 => "{0,number,¤UNESCAPED# ###}" 
1.9.2p290 :002 > escaped = "{0,number,\u00A4ESCAPED# ###}"
 => "{0,number,¤ESCAPED# ###}"
```

Note that escaped and unescaped display the same way:

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > escaped.inspect
 => "\"{0,number,¤ESCAPED# ###}\""
```

The [`String.inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html#method-i-inspect) method is supposed to show special characters escaped:

```
1.9.2p290 :004 > escaped.dump
 => "\"{0,number,\\u{a4}ESCAPED# ###}\"" 
1.9.2p290 :005 > unescaped.dump
 => "\"{0,number,\\u{a4}UNESCAPED# ###}\""
```

`dump` is supposed to do the same thing.

Anyone know of a way to distinguish between escaped and unescaped Unicode characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "Unicode character?"  Do you mean codepoints above 128?

Comment: mike, by unicode character i mean a character that's encoded in unicode, like '¤', and cant be encoded in ascii. the special characters from this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: that list includes all ASCII code-points.  See the first section "Basic Latin".  Maybe what you want are non-[BMP codepoints](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#basic_multilingual_plane)?

Comment: Mike, I'm not too sure about individual code points. I really need to know if my input file has "\u00a4" or "¤" but ruby is converting the former into the latter. I think the conversion happens when the file is read in and encoding is set to UTF-8. Did I lose the extra characters?

Comment: edit your question to include the code that reads the file and specifies the encoding.  Ideally, a [short self-contained runnable example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions).

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > unescaped = "{0,number,¤ESCAPED# ###}"
 => "{0,number,¤UNESCAPED# ###}" 
1.9.2p290 :002 > escaped = "{0,number,\u00A4ESCAPED# ###}"
 => "{0,number,¤ESCAPED# ###}"
```

In the above case it doesn't just display it the same way, but the strings are exactly equal.The parser converts unicode escape sequences to the respective characters when parsing the program source code.

So in the above case, there is nothing to distinguish from. And there is no way for the program itself to know whether you wrote the string literal using escape sequences or literal letters. It's same as writing a numeric literal like `000`, all you get is an int with the value of `0`, there is no way to know how many zeroes there was in the source code.

Comment: That's what I feared. I'm assuming it gets converted when the file is read in. I need to figure out a way to make the parser behave differently.

Comment: @rajatbanerjee By parser I meant the ruby interpreter that reads your source file, if you read a custom file directly in your program that contains `\uxxxx`, then you will get `\uxxxx` literally unless you process it.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to write a runnable example for Mike, I found my solution. It turns out that the string munging I did in to make the string into an object with properties (language, key, message, error count, etc), also interpreted the string into its unescaped unicode format.

This little example works and helped me figure out that I need to check for '\u' before munging the string.

```
infile = File.new('demo-messages.properties', "r", encoding: Encoding::UTF_8)
while (line = infile.gets)
  if line.ascii_only?
    puts "line contains ascii only: #{line}"
  else
    puts "line contains non-ascii text: #{line}"
  end

  #the important part
  if line.inspect.include?('\u') #this check actually works
    puts "line has escaped unicode characters: #{line}"
  else
    puts "line has un-escaped unicode characters: #{line}"
  end
end
infile.close

# FILE: demo-mesages.properties
escaped=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,\u00A4# ###} de plus.
with_utf8_char=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,¤# ###} de plus.
```

Output:

```
$ ruby runnable_example.rb 
line contains non-ascii text: escaped=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,\u00A4# ###} de plus.
line has escaped unicode characters: escaped=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,\u00A4# ###} de plus.
line contains non-ascii text: with_utf8_char=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,¤# ###} de plus.
line has un-escaped unicode characters: with_utf8_char=Cela vous coûte environ {0,number,¤# ###} de plus.
```